# Additional selector window in the grid in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Tell me please, how can I remove this bug?

If I clicking on the selector field underneath this field, another selector field appears.

[extra field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHEO4.png)

Comment: Hi you will need to share that part of your code.

Comment: I have too many dependencies, I cannot transfer them all, but there is no such problem in SalesDemo. I thought maybe someone just came across this problem and it is in aspx.

Comment: When I find a solution, I will definitely share

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the reason. The reason was hiding in the RowTemplate

templete assumes mandatory implementation, and if not, then it just throws an empty line on the View

after I commented out the rowTamplate everything worked correctly

[is shown here more clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InMCI.png)